# How to fix a missing solr tomcat6 config on a Debian Wheezy?

Tags: tomcat, solr, debian, aptitude

I installed `solr-tomcat` with

```
aptitude install solr-tomcat
```

on an up to date Debian Wheezy. That results in the following error message:

```
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 solr-tomcat
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Ein Paket konnte nicht installiert werden. Versuch, dies zu lösen:
solr-tomcat (3.6.0+dfsg-1) wird eingerichtet ...
[....] Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat6cat: /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/policy.d/05solr.policy: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten von solr-tomcat (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 solr-tomcat
```

It seems that the Debian package is missing the `/var/lib/tomcat6/conf/policy.d/05solr.policy` file.

Can I copy some sort of default config? Where could I find it? Google didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package solr-tomcat seems to be brocken. So I followed the instructions I found here: 
http://ctors.net/2014/02/07/solr4_tomcat7_debian7

in the `config/sunspot.yml` I had to use the name of the core I added:

```
path: /solr/name_of_the_core
```